# Angular - hiding/showing sections reset form data

Tags: angular, toggle, hide, show

I have a `form` with some `input` fields and some `select` field, like below:

```
<div class="form-row ">
<div on-click="datiReferentiBancaClicked = !datiReferentiBancaClicked"></div>
<div class="form-row" *ngIf="!datiReferentiBancaClicked">
<label>Nome</label>
<input type="text" id="refbnkNome" [ngModel]="richiesta.refbnkNome" formControlName="refbnkNome" placeholder="Nome">
</div>
</div>
```

So the first `div` toggles the second. The problem is that when I hide the second `div` and I have some data inside the fields, this data resets as the `div` hides. Why does this happens? Do I have to set some property? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more code. So that i can easily understand your question

Comment: use (click) and not ng-click!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ngHide instead of ngIf. It will only collapse the element and make it invisible whereas ngIf completely renoves the element from the DOM.

Comment: That was it. [hidden]="datiRichiestaClicked" worked like a charm.

Comment: I was re-thinking about that before and it makes perfectly sense. Because [hidden] just hides the elements while the *ngIf directive adds/removes the element from the DOM, and of course I'm losing my data.

Comment: ngHide is for angularJS not angular

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ngStyle]="myFunction" to hide your div instead of *ngIf

Then in your component:

```
myFunction() {
  if (!datiReferentiBancaClicked) 
    return {'visibility':'visible'}
  else
    return {'visibility':'hidden'}
}
```

or

bind to the [hidden] attribute

```
<div [hidden]="datiReferentiBancaClicked"></div>
```

*ngIf removes the element form the DOM where visibility:hidden does not.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="form-row">
<div ng-click="datiReferentiBancaClicked = !datiReferentiBancaClicked">Toggle</div>
<div class="form-row" ng-show="!datiReferentiBancaClicked">
<label>Nome</label>
<input type="text" id="refbnkNome" ng-model="richiesta.refbnkNome" placeholder="Nome">
</div>
<div class="form-row" ng-hide="datiReferentiBancaClicked">
// if datiReferentiBancaClicked is true!. This div will be active!
</div>
</div>
// This code is example for toggle
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation along with your answer if at all possible.